# Passenger only works with RailsEnv set to development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger

I must be doing something stupid.

I'm trying to use Passenger to deploy my app on Apache.  I get the static 500 error page from rails unless I add

```
RailsEnv production
```

to my Virtual Host file.

Here is the working file:

```
  <VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName ror.weaponxo.com
   DocumentRoot /home/ubuntu/Development/test_app/public
   RailsEnv development
   <Directory /home/ubuntu/Development/test_app/public>
     AllowOverride all
     Options -MultiViews
   </Directory>
  </VirtualHost>
```

Do I need to somehow tell rails that the environment is production?

I can't find where log messages are sent either, so debugging has been near impossible.  Here's a related question I asked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9243272/passenger-ruby-on-rails-issues

Thanks

I'm using Rails 3.2.1, Apache2, Ubuntu 10.04

Comment: Is there any difference between this question and the one you linked to?

Comment: I got it to "work" by adding the RailsEnv.  That feels hacky, so I wanted to keep the other question opened while I checked out this avenue

Comment: Sorry - I might have misunderstood the question (maybe because of the title). Does it work if you add 'RailsEnv production'? In case you do not specify the RailsEnv explicitly, it will fall back to development mode. In development mode, you do not need to precompile your assets.

Comment: @blackbird07-You were right, it was the assets pipeline.  I had actually just changed `environments/production.rb` to compile the assets, but your answer is the more rails way.  This step also helps with the other question, but still leaves some parts of the other question open.  I've updated the other question to reflect that.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you are using the rails asset pipeline? If so, make sure to run

```
rake assets:precompile
```

on your deployed app. For more information, please have a look here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#precompiling-assets